# Syntax highlighting of diffs of code

Tags: software-development, diff

When I'm viewing a diff, I can highlight the diff syntax, for example using [colordiff](http://www.colordiff.org/):

[image: colordiff screenshot]

(image linked from the web site). However, for tasks like code reviews, I'd really like to have the syntax to be highlighted for the particular programming language, and on top of that have visual marks for removed and added lines (for example removed darker, added brighter). Is there such a 2-level syntax highlighting tool?

Comment: Is this close to what you want? https://www.semanticdesigns.com/Products/SmartDifferencer/COBOLSmartDifferencerExample.html?Home=COBOLSmartDifferencer#RDzPlugin

Comment: @IraBaxter Yes, something in that direction.